# How to use XSLT to transform XML output of DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, xslt, xml-serialization, datacontractserializer

I have become confused due to all of the samples using DataContractSerializer only handling one single object. I have a collection of objects, let's call it `List<Ticket> tickets`. I can get a the DataContractSerializer to write each object using a `foreach (var ticket in tickets)`, but afterward I need to run a transform on the XML in order to be sure it is properly formatted. However, when using the `Transform` method of a `XmlCompiledTransform` I continue receiving the error `"Unexpected end of file while parsing Name has occurred. Line 447, position 28."`

Below is my code, all constructive criticism is welcome.

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms, settings))
    {
        var ser = new DataContractSerializer(tickets.GetType());
        writer.WriteStartDocument(true);
        writer.WriteStartElement("Tickets");
        foreach (var ticket in tickets)
        {
            ser.WriteObject(writer, ticket);
        }
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndDocument();
        ms.Position = 0;
        var xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
        xslt.Load(xsltFp);
        using (var output = new FileStream(xmlFp, FileMode.Create))
        {
            xslt.Transform(XmlReader.Create(ms), null, output);
            output.Position = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is on line 447, position 28?

Comment: It just cuts off in the middle of one of the nodes without completely writing all of the document. That's what the error means... what is actually there is negligible. It's almost as if the memory stream isn't resizing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. At the end of the `foreach` loop, I needed to call `writer.Flush();`. This effectively flushes the stream buffer before we start writing another object.